# Блокирование базы в больших циклах

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть некий скрипт, который принимает массив данных, (допустим это csv-файл), и в цикле добавляет данные из этого массива в базу в виде новых записей (использую `symfony\doctrine`). Кроме добавления могут быть еще сторонние запросы к этой же базе. Пусть скрипт работает 5-6 минут, и запущен он был из админки веб-сайта. Почему с этого момента сайт более становится недоступным, (именно этот сайт, и именно php-скрипты, соседние сайты работают, а с этого сайта исправно раздается статика), пока не закончится цикл работы скрипта?

Доктрина блокирует доступ к базе, или проблема в чем-то другом? Замечал такую же картину на некоторых шаред-хостингах, когда из панели вызываешь архивацию папки большого размера, страницы перестают некоторое время обновляться, nginx выдает gateway timeout, при этом на этом же хостинге но под другим аккаунтом все работает исправно.

Объясните эффект, плиз.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL-же, чего вы от неё хотите? Таблица блокируется и пока транзацкия не закроется, доступ не получить. Возможно стоит покрутить transaction isolation (если он у неё есть, конечно). И ни при чём тут nginx. Gateway timeout это просто потому, что случается таймаут ожидания блокировки.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, при вставке данных, таблица блокируется на чтение и PHP скрипты не могут получить  данные из БД, соответственно может сложится впечатление что php скрипты не отвечают вовсе...

Возможно у SQL выборки php скриптов сайта ниже приоритет чем у "админского" скрипта.

PS:с nginx дела не имел, просьба не пинать если чето вообще не в тему написал :)